# Floating & Expanding Div -CSS/HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

In this link see those 2 floating buttons on the top right side. Purchase theme and send us a message....
http://themes.dfd.name/ronneby/thirty_seventh/

This is what I have now.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12360312/float/index.html

I know how to put an icon infront of the text using CSS ::before and content property. But I can't figure out how that text remains hidden and slides in on hover.

Can anyone help?
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far. There is more than one way to hide text to get the effect you want but with regards to the first link you sent, it looks to me like the text is always there but it's positioned outside the viewport

Comment: Here is a very simple fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ykq8wqu2/) to show you what I mean.

Comment: Thank you Samurai. That's what I want. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to hide the text. You can create a 'text + icon' block, manipulate it's left (or right) margin so only a part of it shows on your screen, and on hover, change the left (or right) margin to show the block.

HTML

```
<div id="slide">
  <span>Click Me [icon]</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slide {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: -65px;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#slide:hover {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle for this](https://jsfiddle.net/s372pnw6/).

Comment: Thank you Misaal. That's what I want. Thank you